# $D \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ so that $f(z):=z^2$ is diffeomorphism

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, functions

$f:\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$

$$f(z):=z^2$$

How can I find the largest possible *open* set $D \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ so that $f$ is a diffeomorphism and determine $f(D)$?

I know that $f(-z)=f(z)$.

My guess is that it's a diffeomorphism on $D_1$:= $\{z \in \mathbb{C}: \Re(z)>0$} or $D_2$:= $\{z \in \mathbb{C}: \Re(z)<0$}.

$f(D_1)=\mathbb{C} \setminus \{z \in \mathbb{R}:z \le0\}$ or $f(D_2)=\mathbb{C} \setminus \{z \in \mathbb{R}:z \le 0\}$.

Then $f:D_1\to f(D_1)$ and $f:D_2\to f(D_2)$ are bijetive functions and their derivatives are continuous.-

Comment: Where is this map bijective?

Answer (score 2):

Both of $D_1$ and $D_2$ are largest open sets on which $f$ is a diffeomorphism.  So is $\{z: \text{Re}(a z) > 0\}$ for any $a \in \mathbb C \backslash \{0\}$.
Thus there is no such thing as **the** largest.